# delphi defining a const multidimensional arrays with mixed static and dynamic elements

Tags: delphi, pascal

Is it possible to mix static and dynamic arrays when creating a multidimensional array and then use that to define a const of that type.
The compiler does not appear to have an issue with the following so I assume its legal to mix dynamic and static arrays like this...

```
TSoftKeyBase = (skEmptyCommandLine, skChannelsSelected);
TSoftKeySet = array of array of String;
TSoftKeys = array[TSoftKeyBase] of TSoftKeySet;
```

When I try to define a const for this array I keep getting "Ordinal type required" on the inner list of elements. Am I pushing beyond the scope of the language?

```
const
  SOFT_KEYS: TSoftKeys =
      [
        [
          ['Select Previous', 'Page',         'Close',        'SC',             'Park',             'MORE >'],
          ['Output',          'FX',           'Macro',        'Select Active',  'Select Changed',   'MORE >'],
          ['Cue List',        'Re Cue List',  'Load',         'Inclusive Mode', 'Active Sel Mode',  'MORE >'],
          ['If',              'View',         'Scroll To',    '',               '',                 'MORE >']
        ],
        [
          ['Select Previous', 'Last',         'Next',         'Clear Selection','Park',             'MORE >'],
          ['Down %',          'Up %',         'Home',         'Select Active',  'Select Changed',   'MORE >'],
          ['Virtual DSC',     'HiLight',      'LoLight',      'Fan',            'Offset',           'MORE >'],
          ['',                '',             '',             '',               '@ ATTs',           'MORE >']
        ]
      ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use normal parentheses at the outer-most level (`array[TSoftKeyBase]`), because it is a static array (and not a dynamic array or a set).

```
const
  SOFT_KEYS: TSoftKeys =
      (
        [
          ['Select Previous', 'Page',         'Close',        'SC',             'Park',             'MORE >'],
          ['Output',          'FX',           'Macro',        'Select Active',  'Select Changed',   'MORE >'],
          ['Cue List',        'Re Cue List',  'Load',         'Inclusive Mode', 'Active Sel Mode',  'MORE >'],
          ['If',              'View',         'Scroll To',    '',               '',                 'MORE >']
        ],
        [
          ['Select Previous', 'Last',         'Next',         'Clear Selection','Park',             'MORE >'],
          ['Down %',          'Up %',         'Home',         'Select Active',  'Select Changed',   'MORE >'],
          ['Virtual DSC',     'HiLight',      'LoLight',      'Fan',            'Offset',           'MORE >'],
          ['',                '',             '',             '',               '@ ATTs',           'MORE >']
        ]
      );
```

Simpler examples:

```
type
  TTest = array[0..2] of Integer; // static array

const
  Data: TTest = (10, 20, 30);
```

and

```
type
  TTest = array of Integer; // dynamic array

const
  Data: TTest = [10, 20, 30];
```

and

```
type
  TTest = set of Byte; // set

const
  Data: TTest = [10, 20, 30];
```